# Anyone who has detailed documentation about the algorithms of the package navfh？

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand how the [navfh](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn?distro=hydro) works? it seems to use an improved dijkstra algorithms to get the shortest path. But I can't clear my thoughts about the details. It maintains two arrays,one is converted from costmap, the another one is potential value(what I am confused with). Anyone who knows well may can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198368/anyone-who-has-detailed-documentation-about-the-algorithms-of-the-package-navfh%EF%BC%9F/) by [ShareIQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/9001/shareiq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you read the [ICRA2010 paper](http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/ICRA2010_Marder-Eppstein) linked from the main [navigation wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)?

P.S. - if you're asking questions about a package, **please** spell the name of the package correctly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0